# How many domains can Traefik secure with HTTPS, any upper limit?

Tags: lets-encrypt, traefik

Is there any upper limit for how many domains Traefik can secure, via Let'sEncrypt?
(I know Let'sEncrypt has rate limits; that's not what this is about.)

If Traefik places all domains / hostnames in a single certificate, seems there's an upper limit at 100 — see: https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/maximum-number-of-sites-on-one-certificate/10634/3 — does Traefik work this way?

However if Traefik generates one new cert, per domain / hostname, then I suppose there is no upper limit. Is this the case?

Is the behaviour different if `acme.onDemand = true` is set, 
versus if `acme.onHostRule = true` is set? Maybe in one case Traefik stores all domains / hostnames in the same cert, in another, in different certs?

<sub>(Background: I build a SaaS and organizations that start using it, provide their own custom domains. I really don't think the following is the case, but still I'm slightly worred that, maybe I'm accidentally adding a max-100-organizations restriction when integrating with Traefik.)</sub>

Comment: Do you use wildcards? In that case, one cert should be able to support any amount of sub-domains. But if you want none-sub-domain certs, I think its basically just the rate limiting that is the issue.
Be sure to use a kvs for the certs though, only using a json file could be an issue when dealing with that amount of certificates.

Comment: Worst case, if you hit a hard limit, change ingress controller/load balancer to one which can take more! :)

Comment: @Jite I have my own wildcard cert for customers/users who don't provide their own custom domain. However, those who do use their own custom domain, don't use wildcards, instead, an exact hostname like `forum.example.com` (their domain and their DNS server).  — Thanks for the tips about KVS; I was previously wondering how well a JSON file could work at a larger scale, if it'd become rather slow, eventually. Didn't know one coud use a KVS (key value store) instead.

Comment: Its highly recommended to use Etcd or Consul when running in cluster, Consul is fairly easy to set up, especially using Kubernetes or Docker swarm.
I would recommend that you allow users to add a domain and point it to your cluster, then set your traefik ingress/lb/server to generate wildcard certs for the domain, so that they have one domain, but can create unlimited subdomains with the wildcard. :)

Comment: @Jite ok thanks for the info and ideas. 1) Actually I'm actively trying to avoid things like etcd and consul and Kurbernetes, to keep the tech stack simple. 2) I think people wouldn't want to point a wildcard domain to my servers — that'd be of no use to them. Probably they'd want to point any wildcard, to their own servers instead. It's enough with a sub domain like `forum.org-name.com` pointing to my server :- )

Comment: If you are not intending to scale the program, then I wouldn't be that scared for the limit of certs possible to serve, it will be hard to run a SaaS without some type of scaling!
But you might just be using traefik for load-balancing, then it might be okay, hehe.
Either way, good luck and hope you find a good solution :)

Comment: @Jite I do intend to scale the program, and I'd start with adding more RAM and CPUs to a single VPS. This will likely be more than enough for 1000+ organizations with custom sub domains (keeping in mind that nowadays there're servers with like 256 GB RAM). I think I'd run into any Traefik-max-100 limitation, long before I'd need to scale out horizontally.

Comment: B.t.w. about using a KVS: it's possible to start with a JSON file and then migrate to a KVS via a `traefik storeconfig ...` command. Docs [here](https://docs.traefik.io/user-guide/kv-config/#store-configuration-in-key-value-store). Which means one can avoid adding KVS like etcd and consul, until later when really needed for sure.

Comment: @Jite I got an answer in the Slack support chat, about Traefik and any max num hostnames. See my answer here. (It's one cert per hostname = unlimited)

Comment: Looks like it is limited to 100 when using consul though: https://docs.traefik.io/configuration/acme/#as-a-key-value-store-entry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no upper limit. Traefik generates one cert per hostname.

From Traefik's Slack chat:

> basically Traefik creates one certificate by host if you are using `onHostRule` or `onDemand`.
>   You can create one certificate for multiple domains by using `domains` https://docs.traefik.io/configuration/acme/#domains.

(This chat message, however, probably it'll disappear soon — Slack's 10k limit: https://traefik.slack.com/archives/C0CDT22PJ/p1546183883145900?thread_ts=1546183554.145800&cid=C0CDT22PJ )

(Note, though, that `onDemand` is deprecated — see: https://github.com/containous/traefik/issues/2212)